# Is it necessary to appcache images?

Tags: html

The biggest issue I've encountered when using HTML5's appcache ability is that including too many files makes for very slow cache loading and updating. Images are the biggest culprit as they're large and can't be concatenated in to a single file, and downloading / cacheing many files is a particular problem on mobile devices. Additionally, on iOS devices there seems to be an issue with pulling appcache'd resources, for even a modest webapp this process takes several minutes. So, reducing the number of files in the appcache to just a minified JavaScript & CSS file makes for a much snappier process.

What I've ended up doing is removing images from the cache manifest entirely and letting them be stored in the traditional browser cache. I've tested across a variety of devices, browsers, etc. and am able to pull up my webapp while offline and all images load just fine. If images are reasonably static, is there any problem one can see with just relying on traditional cacheing?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that you should use appcache is for persistent offline content.

I might be cached in the browser for a while, but that does not guarantee that it will stay cached. The OS may decide to clear the cache whenever it's low on memory.

In short, don't rely on the browser cache to keep your files available offline forever. This is where appcache comes in.

On a side note; if your images are relatively small, you might want to create a spritesheet.

Comment: Good point about browsers clearing cache, though I'm not sure what the rules are for cache clearing. I've never heard of browsers automatically clearing their cache due to memory constraints since cache is pulled from the HDD. Though obviously users may clear their cache.

Comment: ...I thought cache was cleared based on the Cache-Control & Expires headers or if a user manually clears their cache. I definitely agree traditional web cache is less reliable than appcache. I use appcache to persist webapps for short-term network outages (subways, basement pubs, stormy weather). I like the spritesheet idea.

Comment: The rules for cache clearing differ from device to device.
It's very likely that a mobile device such as a smartphone will allow its cache to be a certain size and pop elements from the cache whenever that buffer is full.

Cache-Control and Expires headers are guidelines set by W3C, anyone is allowed to implement these but don't expect everyone to strictly follow these rules. Exceptions will most likely always occur.

And yes, users can manually clear cache as well.
But they can also manually clear the appcache.

I hope that helps you with your question.